# Implicit DataTemplate equivalent for Silverlight + Prism

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism

I'm building an Silverlight application which consists of a grid containing multiple different widgets. Each widget is implemented as a ViewModel class which are then binded to grid.

With WPF I'd use implicit DataTemplates to bind certain ViewModel to a certain View. But since Silverlight doesn't support this feature I'm a bit stuck.

So far I've only thought of implementing some sort of global DataTemplateSelector to which each Prism module would register matching ViewModel and View pairs at startup. Then I could use Unity to inject this selector to grid and achieve what I want but this doesn't feel like the best way to do it.

Any ideas how should I do this?

Comment: You could answer your own question and mark it as answer yourself.

Comment: Manoj, thanks for the tip. Re-edited the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more googling and found few articles about TemplateContentControl (e.g. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arielbh/archive/2010/10/24/how-to-develop-mvvm-silverlight-applications-with-prism.aspx) and after some testing it seems to be just what I was looking for.

Comment: I've been using this approach successfully for several years now. Feel free to drop me a line if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.viewmodel.datatemplateselector%28PandP.38%29.aspx#) for Silverlight.

Read about it more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430869%28PandP.40%29.aspx#DataTemplates).